# Criar uma variável dentro de um xpath

Tags: python, aplicação-web, while, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Estou tentando criar uma automação em python - (Web scraping) que possui um loop no qual o xpath vai se alterando toda vez que realiza um click no local desejado, então percebi que no xpath só se altera um digito:

```
//*[@id="j_id184:dados:0:j_id306"]
//*[@id="j_id184:dados:1:j_id306"]
//*[@id="j_id184:dados:2:j_id306"]
```

Teria como colocar esse número como uma variável?
Ou existe outra forma se fazer isso?

código considerando apenas um objeto:

```
self.webDriverWait(self.driver,15).until(self.ec.element_to_be_clickable((self.by.XPATH,'//[@id="j_id184:dados:0:j_id306"]')))
click_nfs = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="j_id184:dados:0:j_id306"]')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar formatar a string. Para isso o as strings em python possuem um método chamado `format`.

Segue um exemplo:

```
format_xpath = '//*[@id="j_id184:dados:{numero}:j_id306"]'

for i in range(10):
    # para cada interacao o valor de numero é alterado
    # Exemplo quando i vale 0: '//*[@id="j_id184:dados:0:j_id306"]'
    # Exemplo quando i vale 1: '//*[@id="j_id184:dados:1:j_id306"]'
    # Exemplo quando i vale 9: '//*[@id="j_id184:dados:9:j_id306"]'
    xpath = format_xpath.format(numero=i)
    print(xpath)
    element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    element.click()
```

Comment: Era exatamente o que eu procurava, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode formatar a string do xpath. Exemplos:

```
click_nfs = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="j_id184:dados:{n}:j_id306"]')
```

ou

```
click_nfs = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="j_id184:dados:%d:j_id306"]' % n)
```

onde `n` é o número em que você está.

Comment: Obrigado! Era o que eu precisava